# How to keep controller and model on different machine in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, browser

I have recently gone thru several articles on AngularJS. As AngularJS maintains controllers and models separately from view. As soon as model gets updated it updates View automatically and vice versa as it is two way binding. But as much I have gone thru all the articles I have found that all views, models and controllers are managed on client side.

Do we have any way to put controllers and models on different machines than client side ?

Comment: Sorry , what do you mean by **different machines** ?

Comment: what do you mean by model, back-end ?

Comment: like ruby on rails, controllers are running on server side. but in angularjs controller runs on client side. so can we do similar here too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not automatically. AngularJS is a *client-side* MV* framework. There are also server-side frameworks and even some combos like Meteor that run on both sides. But always there is some messaging back and forth, and at the end of the day, what is it you wish to do on the server? Servers and clients are almost always very different, and where a client might be drawing forms and tables, a server might be reading/writing database queries or managing multimedia assets. That means there's rarely a benefit to a 1:1 duplication of functionality in both environments.

I would suggest you evaluate the excellent [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) framework for NodeJS. This is a great building block for server-side MV* apps, especially when combined with a good templating library like Swig. You can easily create a CRUD API here (in just a few minutes) that manages creating/updating data objects in a model and storing them in a database like MySQL, Mongo, or something like Redis. Then, back in AngularJS, you can use $resource, Restangular, or similar to map between the two.

This technique has a few more steps in it than Meteor would, but it gives you an incredible amount of flexibility and doesn't take very much code to produce.